# Why does "Tap to click" not work in many games?

Tags: trackpad, games, click

I have enabled "Tap to Click" in the trackpad options in OSX (10.9.2), but it doesn't work in many games that I play.  Instead, I have to physically press the trackpad which is really inconvenient for me...

Are there any settings to fix/change this behavior?

EDIT:  I forgot to mention that sometimes it does work but requires two or more taps to register as a click...

Comment: Same issue here with many, if not most, games, including standalone titles, not only Steam.