# MacBook Pro 2016 Left Click lag in games?

Tags: mouse, trackpad, performance, games

I've recently purchased a 2016 13-inch MacBook Pro w/ Touch Bar and I've noticed something incredibly strange when playing games. Left-clicking with any pointer (either the trackpad or mouse) results in a noticeable delay in a game's response. So far, I've noticed it while playing League of Legends, Borderlands 2, and Mark of the Ninja.

In the case of League, left clicking doesn't cause the game to freeze up, but rather the game does not register the left click unless the click is held down for a longer time. This is true for both a mouse and the trackpad.

For BL2, left clicking anywhere, either in the menus or in the 3D environment , will result in a slight delay before the click is registered, but will then visually lock up cursor movement. Objects in the 3D environment still move at full FPS, but the player First Person camera will briefly freeze, then cut to where it WOULD be if the freeze never occurred. In this way, left-clicking doesn't freeze the game per say, but rather freezes movement of the game camera briefly.

Mark of the Ninja has an issue similar to League, where left clicking is not registered unless the click is held down.

From these three scenarios, I am led to believe that the issue does not lie exclusively with the trackpad or mouse (since the problem occurs with both input mechanisms). I also believe that the problem exists outside of Steam (which was used to play both BL2 and MotN) since LoL was affected. I have tried adjusting double-click speed in Trackpad and Mouse settings, which did not help. I also tried turning off Force-Click and Three-Finger Drag for the trackpad, which also did not help.

The problem seems only to occur in games; navigating around the Desktop and Finder is speedy and responsive.

Has anyone else had this issue and/or knows how to fix it? I am running MacOS Sierra 10.12.5.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I found the solution after a long time searching....

As it turns out, a third party app called "Magnet" was causing the delay. Many other games have had similar issues due to this app running in the background.

Comment: This was my issue, no idea how you found it but this was super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I would really like to know how you found it as well :) Thank you for this!

Comment: I have no idea how you debug something like this issue, but quitting my window management app solved it 100%, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What is your FPS during the game? Most games only check for new input each time a new frame is rendered. Thus less frames = less input checks. The fact that you don't get this problem while doing normal tasks supports this hypothesis since navigating around the desktop is easier on your GPU than gaming. That is to say you get higher FPS on the desktop and therefore more input checks.

Also see this [similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130783/why-does-tap-to-click-not-work-in-many-games?rq=1).

Comment: FPS during these games is high, around 45-60 FPS. Also, the fram rate doesn't drop when left clicking; the mouse pointer freezes. While the mouse pointer is "frozen" the game is not; entities in the background move around at full fps. Also, tap to click works, and has the same problem as a mouse or a hard click.